# Keeping jQuery AJAX success response in proper scope/context

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, scope

I have content that is generated dynamically with each content item containing a simple one-button form to add/remove one of these content items to/from a favorite list. I'm using jQuery's ajax method to post the form and get my response(s) and everything works perfectly except the success call-back is being applied to every button element in each form when it should only be applied to the button clicked. I've been struggling with this for hours and not sure why it isn't in the proper scope.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('button').text(response);
        };
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here is the forms that are generated:

```
if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    $addFave = NULL;
    $favorites = DB::connectDB()->query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user = '{$userid}' AND favid = '{$favid}'");
    $matches = mysqli_num_rows($favorites);
    if ($matches == 0) {
        $addFave = '
            <form action="../app/parsers/faves_addremove.php" method="post" class="ajax">
                <input type="hidden" name="user" value="' . escape($user->data()->id) . '">
                <input type="hidden" name="favid" value="' . ++$nfave . '">
                <button id="addFave" class="btn rb-faucet-button btn-default bg-color-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add To Faves</button>
            </form>
        ';
    } else {
        $addFave = '
            <form action="../app/parsers/faves_addremove.php" method="post" class="ajax">
                <input type="hidden" name="user" value="' . escape($user->data()->id) . '">
                <input type="hidden" name="favid" value="' . ++$nfave . '">
                <button id="addFave" class="btn rb-faucet-button btn-default bg-color-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove From Faves</button>
            </form>
        ';
    }
} else {
    $addFave = '';
}
```

And finally here is the script ajax works with to add/remove from the database and generate my responses:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    if (isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['favid'])) {
        if ($_POST['user'] = $user->data()->id) {
            $userid = $_POST['user'];
            $favid = $_POST['favid'];

            $favorites = DB::connectDB()->query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user = '{$userid}' AND favid = '{$favid}'");
            $matches = mysqli_num_rows($favorites);
            if ($matches == '0') {
                DB::connectDB()->query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid) VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$favid}')");
                echo "Added";
            }
            if ($matches != '0') {
                DB::connectDB()->query("DELETE FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user = '{$userid}' AND favid = '{$favid}'");
                echo "Deleted";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid user.";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid session.";
}
```

If I click on the button to add an item to the ajaxfavourites table my response text of "Added" is applied to each button element on the page inside any form with the "ajax" class. What am I missing? I though I had this properly in scope and nothing I have tried seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are addressing all the buttons within your success callback, `$('button')` will return all the buttons on the page.

you should use something like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    that.find('button').text(response);
}
```

Since `that` is referring to the `form` you are working in, the [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) should retrieve all `button` elements within the form.

If you have more than one button within the form, you should give it a descriptive class. i.e `that.find('button.useThisButton').text(response);`

Comment: Beautiful... Was staring me right in the face... Thank you very much!